# How to get a copy of a Woocommerce order on an e-mail?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am currently making a webshop for a client, and they wish (if possible) to avoid using WooCommerce and Wordpress as much as possible.

Currently the buyer receives a confirmation e-mail with the order details, the billing address, and other information about their purchase.

**My question:**

- Would it be possible to get a copy of this mail, sent to their e-mail automatically?

The client currently handles all orders over e-mail, and wish to continue in this fashion.

Thanks a lot.

I've tried troubleshooting on Google, but without any luck. I've always tried downloading some plugins that I thought might help, but again without any luck. Running WooCommerce on Wordpress.

Answer (score 2):

Found the way to fix this... If anyone reads in the future:

Go to:

WooCommerce < Settings < Emails < New Order... There you can specify an e-mail.